# Which Google APIs to implement to access files in different Drive locations?

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-api, google-drive-api

I assume I can achieve my goal through the use of a Google Project. Please redirect me to the right place if this is not the right place for this question.

Problem: I have 3 employees with their own separate folders in a Google Drive that I own. They each have a "TripLog.xls" file in their respective folders . I need to open each one and extract data. Eventually I'll be writing data, but for now I'm focusing on reading the data.

The paths are organized as follows:

> Employees\John Smith\Trips\TripLog.xls
> Employees\Albert Cooley\Trips\TripLog.xls
> Employees\Rob Ford\Trips\TripLog.xls

From my understanding of `Sheets API`, I create a service account which generates an email. I configure the file to share with the service account email. That's fine for one-off scenarios, but right now it's for 3 files. When there are 15 individuals, it seems awkward to require 15 service accounts.

Is there a way to use the `Google Drive API` so I can navigate the folders and read the spreadsheet data?

Comment: At Google Drive, all files and folders are managed by the unique IDs. So if you have already known the IDs of each file of `TripLog.xls`, you can directly access to them using the IDs. If you have never known those IDs, in your folder structure, for example, when the folder ID of `Trips` under `John Smith` folder, you can retrieve the file of `TripLog.xls` using the search query of `'### folder ID of Trips ###' in parents and name='TripLog.xls'`. If this was not useful for your situation, I apologize. By the way, `TripLog.xls` is the Microsoft Excel file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if this is going to sound too obvious but answering your question if you want to access the files at Google Drive you are gonna need to use the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive).

The location of those file inside drive would not change the API to use. You just need to know the id of every single file, and if you don't then you will need to [search for those files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files) to extract it. If your folder structure makes it difficult try to change it (if you can) so it has a more easier path to follow. Also you could do this `name contains '.xls'` if you just want all the xls files.

From there it's on you what to do with the files. If you want to use them in google sheets and make use of [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api) you will need to re upload them again with the Drive API specifying the [correct MIME type](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types). There is a whole section on [this matter in the drive documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#import_to_google_docs_types).

Finally you don't need to create a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) for every single file. You just need to be sure to share with the service account (and right editor permissions) every spreadsheet that you want to modify.

For this case imagine that the service account is just another account that conveniently doesn't require to go through OAuth2 Consent screen.

Comment: So, using the Drive API I am required to download a file to read or write to it whereas the Sheets API allows me to manipulate the file without downloading.

And, I can use the same service account for all sheets files.

Helpful, actually. Thanks.